# Comparing Two Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to solve this problem:

*Regional and international planes arrive at an airport following independent Poisson processes with rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively. Each regional plane has independently Y people who transfer to the international plane; suppose $f_1 := E(Y)$ and $f_2 := E(Y^2)$ are known. Find the mean and the variance of the quantity of flyers who board the next international plane.*

Here, we need to know how many regional planes arrive before the next international plane. When comparing two exponential random variables, the probability that the regional plane arrives before the international plane is: $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}$ However, I'm unsure how to move forward. Can we use an indicator variable and sum over the number of indicator variables that indicate a regional plane has arrived before an international plane?